# Test for .htaccess rewrites failed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, sugarcrm

I am trying to install SugarCRM Enterprise 7.2 and I keep getting this error during system check:

> Test for .htaccess rewrites failed. This usually means you do not have
>   AllowOverride set up for Sugar directory.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with LAMP, and I am trying to install Sugar to the local path

> var/www/html/sugar_ent_7

I have already tried putting both

```
<Directory /var/www/ >
    Allowoverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

and

```
<Directory /var/www/html/sugar_ent_7 >
Allowoverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

to my

> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

file, and no results. I have also tried making a

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/sugar_ent_7.conf

file with this code

```
<Directory /var/www/html/sugar_ent_7>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

and still nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you restart or reload apache after these changes ?

Comment: Yes, after every change

Comment: What is this `system check`? Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: When you install SugarCRM it checks if your system supports the version you are trying to install. That is a system check. If your server configuration is not set up properly for Sugar to work, it shows you errors. .htaccess is enabled, I get 500 error when I put some garbage in it.

Comment: There is no way for any utility to check if .htaccess is enabled or not. To test that run the test as I suggested.

Comment: Either we don't understand each other, or we don't read each other's posts. I wrote above, that I tried to test .htaccess, I put garbage in it, and I got a 500 error. But, something in my apache configuration must be wrong, as I keep getting the error while trying to install SugarCRM.

Comment: When I was seeing this, it's because mod_rewrite wasn't enabled. It took me two hours to figure it out, and I killed myself when did. I've been dead for three months.

Comment: My mod_rewrite is definitely enabled. I checked it at least 10 times...

Comment: another cause of this error message is simply permissions.  if the sugar root directory and any existing .htaccess file does not allow your apache user to write, the rewrite check will fail.

Answer (score 4):

Run the command

```
a2enmod rewrite;
```

in your terminal and restart your apache.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem.

its aim is just to check the following code exists in your .htaccess:

```
# install/installSystemCheck.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>                                                                             
    RewriteEngine On                                                                                 
    RewriteBase {$basePath}                                                                          
    RewriteRule ^itest.txt$ install_test.txt [N,QSA]                                                 
</IfModule>
```

I don't think SugarCRM is enough to check this setting, so let's just comment it out and make it passed:

```
# 
//    if($res != "SUCCESS") {                                                                     
if(false) {                                                                                   
....
```

Answer (score 2):

This error can also (misleadingly?) occur when sugar tries to address itself vi IP during the system check. When vhosting is configured it cannot find itself via IP, thus an entry to the hosts file can solve this. In the terminal enter:

```
vi /etc/hosts
```

Then add the IP of the system Sugar is running on with the URL you're referring to it, e.g.:

```
123.234.123.234 subdomain.host.com
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# BEGIN SUGARCRM RESTRICTIONS
RedirectMatch 403 (?i).*\.log$
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+not_imported_.*\.txt
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+(soap|cache|xtemplate|data|examples|include|log4php|metadata|modules)/+.*\.(php|tpl)
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+emailmandelivery\.php
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+upload
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+custom/+blowfish
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+cache/+diagnostic
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+files\.md5$
# END SUGARCRM RESTRICTIONS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /dir
    RewriteRule ^cache/jsLanguage/(.._..).js$ index.php?entryPoint=jslang&module=app_strings&lang=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^cache/jsLanguage/(\w*)/(.._..).js$ index.php?entryPoint=jslang&module=$1&lang=$2 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif|js|css|ico)$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                Header set ETag ""
                Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
                Header set Expires "01 Jan 2112 00:00:00 GMT"
        </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer instead of just dumping code in here?